# CWP Database not Found

Tags: mysql, centos7, centos-web-panel

Just did a fresh install of CWP on Centos 7. But when i try to start it i get this error:

```
######################
Update Server Packages
######################
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'root_cwp' in /usr/local/cwpsrv/htdocs/resources/admin/include/functions.php on line 0
PHP Warning:  main(/usr/local/cwpsrv/htdocs/resources/admin/include/postfix.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/cwpsrv/htdocs/resources/admin/include/functions.php on line 0
PHP Warning:  main(): Failed opening '/usr/local/cwpsrv/htdocs/resources/admin/include/postfix.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/cwp/php71/lib/php') in /usr/local/cwpsrv/htdocs/resources/admin/include/functions.php on line 0
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: db_host_postfix in /usr/local/cwpsrv/htdocs/resources/admin/include/functions.php on line 0
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: db_user_postfix in /usr/local/cwpsrv/htdocs/resources/admin/include/functions.php on line 0
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: db_pass_postfix in /usr/local/cwpsrv/htdocs/resources/admin/include/functions.php on line 0
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: db_name_postfix in /usr/local/cwpsrv/htdocs/resources/admin/include/functions.php on line 0
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'root_cwp' in /usr/local/cwpsrv/htdocs/resources/admin/include/cron.php on line 0
PHP Warning:  mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /usr/local/cwpsrv/htdocs/resources/admin/include/cron.php on line 0
Could not select database root_cwp
```

I have checked and made sure that my Root SQL password and the password in the CWP config file is the same.

But i see that the CWP_root database does not exist in SQL.

Is there any way of reinstalling cwp or fiixing the database without reinstalling the entire server.

Answer (score 1):

login by root 
and write mysql -u root -p after this write your database password and 
SHOW DATABASES; 
in case not exists
 CREATE DATABASE root_cwp ;
 if steps success ، return try your setup 
but is database exists try change database password and return try your setup .
if you can not login to database try mysql_secure_installation  and reset password
or

```
mysql> use mysql;
```

mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("yournewrootpasshere") where User='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit

sorry my bad english
Hope to help you